# Как вставить скопированный номер в MaskedEditText

Tags: java, android

подключил библиотеку compile 'com.github.pinball83:masked-edittext:1.0.3'

Нужно не просто вводить, а чтобы была возможность вставлять скопированный номер телефона, есть ли такой метод у данной библиотеки?

Comment: я думаю ,у нее есть метод `setText()`, как у любого `TextVIew`

Comment: @metalurgus при долгом свапе окошечко со словом paste не появляется

Comment: Дайте, как минимум, ссылку на библиотеку. Я не думаю, что мы должны ее еще искать в интернете ради того ,чтобы помочь вам.

Comment: @metalurgus https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-Edittext

Comment: В методе setOnLongClickListener()  может попробуете?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так,

```
ClipboardManager clipboard;
clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

ClipData cp = myClipboard.getPrimaryClip(); 
ClipData.Item item = cp.getItemAt(0); 
String text = item.getText().toString(); 
edittext.setText(text);
```

Comment: myClipboard это что?

Comment: Обновил ответ...

Comment: выпало 2 ошибки
aused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setOnLongClickListener(android.view.View$OnLongClickListener)' on a null object reference

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setOnLongClickListener(android.view.View$OnLongClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: В буффере есть какие то данные?